# Python Django heroku error "! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)"

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Whenever I type command: `git push heroku master`

```
    Enumerating objects: 32, done.
Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 11.43 KiB | 557.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 32 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.7
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Django==2.1.3 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/e5/2676be45ea49cfd09a663f289376b3888accd57ff06c953297bfdee1fb08/Django-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.7.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/2a/61a8f9719bd6df5b421abd91740cb0595fc3c17b28eaf89fe4f144472ca6/psycopg2-2.7.6.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2018.7 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/0e/2365ddc010afb3d79147f1dd544e5ee24bf4ece58ab99b16fbb465ce6dc0/pytz-2018.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (506kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==4.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_731c5da72f871fc9827c03c3e6dfa9eb/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/2a/b51377ab9826f0551da19951257d2434f46329cd6cfdf9592ea9ca5f6034/whitenoise-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, pytz, Django, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, gunicorn
remote:        Successfully installed Django-2.1.3 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-19.9.0 psycopg2-2.7.6.1 pytz-2018.7 whitenoise-4.1.2
```

**it give error here**

```
remote:
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
remote:            handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 343, in copy_file
remote:            if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 249, in delete_file
remote:            if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 308, in exists
remote:            return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 43, in path
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to arshergon.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/arshergon.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arshergon.git'
```

> python version : 3.6.7
>
> django version : 2.1.3
>
> heroku version : 0.1.4
>
> git version : 2.20.1.windows.1
>
> machine : window 10

I have no staticfiles it is a simple **Hello, World** app

the command I type:

```
git init

git --all

git commit -m "first commit"

git: remote -a websitename

git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Comment: this helped thanks, but I'd love to understand why. Why was this a necessary step?

Answer (score 3):

**Before**: When error's happening

```
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
remote:            for entry in os.scandir(path):
remote:        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_fff79b97/static'
```

As we can observe, the traceback states
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_fff79b97/static'`.
This is because I had my static file @ `root/home/static`, while my **STATICFILES_DIR** is not pointing to that dir. So only thing I did is

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "home", "static"),
]
```

instead of usual `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`.

And if you're just trying without any static files, you can directly use `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` and then push.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't have static files, a [Django Hello World app](https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/) does mention them.

Do check if you can declare `STATIC_ROOT` your settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

(as it is [done in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456080/6309))

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still the same error  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arshergon.git'