# " Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput" even though I have my static_root set

Tags: python, django, heroku

So, I already have my static root set, I did `manage.py collectstatic` so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to push everything to heroku, and I keep getting this error about there not being a path to static files. Am I not providing the correct 'STATIC_ROOT'? I have it as   `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

**traceback**

```
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
remote:            handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 342, in copy_file
remote:            if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 249, in delete_file
remote:            if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 310, in exists
remote:            return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 44, in path
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pacific-refuge-35090.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pacific-refuge-35090.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pacific-refuge-35090.git'
```

**settings.py**

```
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***********************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'


#For Custom Model 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'dating_app.Profile'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    
    #Third party apps
    'bootstrap4', 


    #My apps
    'dating_app',
   

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dating_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dating_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'


USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIR = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dating_app/media')


#Settings for django-bootstrap3
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery' : True,
}
```

Comment: Can you update on the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455469/youre-using-the-staticfiles-app-without-having-set-the-static-root-setting-to-a) ,try the conf in the following way

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

If unsuccessful, please update the results of the following: do you have the same error when you run it locally or in a dev environment?